# Dataframe: How to select for each row different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's consider a dataframe A with three columns: a, b and c. Suppose we have also Series B of the the same size as A. In each row it contains the name of one of the A's column. I want to construct the Series which would contains the values form the table A at columns specified by B.

The simplest example would be the following:

```
idxs = np.arange(0, 5)
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [3, 1, 5, 7, 8],
    'b': [5, 6, 7, 3, 1],
    'c': [2, 7, 8, 2, 1],
}, index=idxs)
B = pd.Series(['b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'], index=idxs)
```

I need to apply some operation which will give the result identical to the following series:

```
C = pd.Series([5, 7, 8, 7, 8], index=idxs)
```

In such a simple example one can perform 'broadcasting' as following on pure numpy arrays:

```
d = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2 }
AA = A.rename(columns=d).as_matrix()
BB = B.apply(lambda x: d[x]).as_matrix()

CC = AA[idxs, BB]
```

That works, but in my real problem I have multiindexed Dataframe, and things become more complicated.

Is it possible to do so, using pandas tools?

The first thing that comes into my mind is:

```
A['idx'] = B;
C = A.apply(lambda x: x[x['idx']], axis=1)
```

It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.lookup`:

```
pd.Series(A.lookup(B.index, B), index=B.index)

0    5
1    7
2    8
3    7
4    8
dtype: int64
```

---

A NumPy solution involving broadcasting is:

```
A.values[B.index, (A.columns.values == B[:, None]).argmax(1)]
# array([5, 7, 8, 7, 8])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: lookup is deprecated in v2